# Regression predictions are more than actual values

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have a mall customers dataset from kaggle, it's 200 customers with 5 features, CustomerID, gender, age, annual income and spending score. Before running regression i first ran k-means to cluster my data, with K = 6 for Spending score(dependent variable) annual income(Independent variable) and age(independent variable). After doing so i ran multiple linear regression for each cluster seperatly, after doing so i printed my predicted values and my actual values and my predicted values are way more than my actual printed values. The predicted y values were 34 (that's exactly the number of values i have in my cluster) and my actual y values are 9. Why don't all of my actual values print?

code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:\Mall_Customers.csv', usecols = ['Age','Spending Score (1-100)', 'Annual Income (k$)'])

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)


kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=6, max_iter=100, random_state=0)
y_kmeans= kmeans.fit_predict(x)

mydict = {i: np.where(kmeans.labels_ == i)[0] for i in range(kmeans.n_clusters)}

dictlist = []
for key, value in mydict.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)

df0 = df[df.index.isin(mydict[0].tolist())]
Y = df0['Spending Score (1-100)']
X = df0[[ 'Annual Income (k$)','Age']]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = None, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X)

print('predicted:', y_pred, sep='\n')
print('actual', y_test, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above doesn't show how you computed `y_pred`. Also, you've called `train_test_split` with a `test_size` of `None` which means you're test set defaults to 25% of the data. If there's 34 items in your cluster that'd be 8.5 so the 9 actual values you're seeing makes sense. To understand why `y_pred` is more than that we'd have to see how you computed it but I'm guessing you did something like `regressor.predict(X)` which would give you predictions on all of the data, not just the test set.

Comment: Yes you are correct that's what i did i used ```y_pred = regressor.predict(X)``` . Sorry for not including it in the code, i had some other print functions and i didn't want people to get confused with those and i accidentaly left that one out. Then how can i print only the test data?

Comment: `y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)` would be the predictions for the test data.